# get the value of a cell of a dataframe based on the value in one of the columns in R

Tags: r

I have an example of a data frame in which columns "a" and "b" have certain values, and in column "c" the values are 1 or 2. I would like to create column "d" in which the value found in the frame will be located at the index specified in column "c".

```
x = data.frame(a = c(1:10), b = c(3:12), c = seq(1:2))
x
    a  b c
1   1  3 1
2   2  4 2
3   3  5 1
4   4  6 2
5   5  7 1
6   6  8 2
7   7  9 1
8   8 10 2
9   9 11 1
10 10 12 2
```

thus column "d" for the first row will contain the value 1, since the index in column "c" is 1, for the second row d = 4, since the index in column "c" is 2, and so on. I was not helped by the standard indexing in R, it just returns the value of the column c. in what ways can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may can create a matrix of row and column numbers to subset values from the dataframe.

```
x$d <- x[cbind(1:nrow(x), x$c)]
x

#    a  b c  d
#1   1  3 1  1
#2   2  4 2  4
#3   3  5 1  3
#4   4  6 2  6
#5   5  7 1  5
#6   6  8 2  8
#7   7  9 1  7
#8   8 10 2 10
#9   9 11 1  9
#10 10 12 2 12
```

If the input is tibble, you need to change the tibble to dataframe to use the above answer.

If you don't want to change to dataframe, here is another option using `rowwise`.

```
library(dplyr)

x <- tibble(x)
x %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(d = c_across()[c])
```

Comment: a little bit wrong, since you need to work in the dataframe type

Comment: @МихаилТабаков What exactly is wrong? A dataframe is what you have provided us as input.

Comment: converting to a matrix does not suit me, as an error occurs "operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: I am not converting to matrix and I don't get any such error on the example you have shared.

Answer (score 1):

By using `dplyr::mutate` and `ifelse`,

```
x %>% mutate(d = ifelse(c == 1, a, b))

    a  b c  d
1   1  3 1  1
2   2  4 2  4
3   3  5 1  3
4   4  6 2  6
5   5  7 1  5
6   6  8 2  8
7   7  9 1  7
8   8 10 2 10
9   9 11 1  9
10 10 12 2 12
```

Comment: this option will not work if the frame is larger